# Using Lynx Cron Job to allow for PHP redirect

Tags: php, redirect, cron, lynx

I have a PHP script which ends with a header redirect, I want to schedule it via a Cron Job.

Reading around took me to the 'lynx' library that I thought was essentially a browser-lite way of doing a Cron Job that would act in the same way as a browser and be able to execute my redirect.

A simplified version of my script looks like:

```
<?php 

// Connect to DB
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/admin/inc/dbconnect.php");

// Check DB for quotes that have not been sent to this client
$query_quotes = "SELECT * FROM quotes WHERE sent_client = 0 LIMIT 1";
$view_request = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['db_connect'], $query_quotes);

// Send to external system and email customer with quote
while ($quotes = mysqli_fetch_array($view_request)){

    $Body = "Email Content";

    // Send email via Swift Mailer

    // Send quote information to third party system via URL redirect
    header('Location: http://exampleurl/?FirstName='.rawurlencode($quotes['name']).'&businessName='.rawurlencode($quotes['company_name']).'.');

}

?>
```

It finds records in my database then sends the customer an email before compiling a URL with their information and redirecting to it. The variables in the URL are then read by a third party system and inputted into their database.

I'm activating the cron job (via Plesk scheduler) like so:

```
/usr/bin/lynx -source http://exampleurl2/script.php > /dev/null
```

I know the script is being executed but the redirect part is not working still, am I doing something wrong with lynx? Also tried recreating the redirect function with cURL but couldn't seem to do so.

Comment: In the end I had to admit defeat on this, used an application called System Scheduler on a windows based server which successfully runs the scripts.

Would still be interested to hear why the lynx solution didn't work!